# Node.js Sequelize Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am working on a Node.js project with typescript.
I am on an Ubuntu machine.
I want to use Sequelize for ORM.

In my previous project, Sequelize worked great including model and migration generations.

Now, I need Sequelize to generate typescript files for models and migrations. For this, I found:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cli-typescript

I tried to install it both locally or globally:

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli-typescript
npm install --save sequelize-cli-typescript
```

But when I run:

```
sequelize init
```

or

```
./node_modules/.bin/sequelize init
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve sequelize package in /home/...
```

Any solution for this? Any other way of generating models and migrations?

Comment: Have u installed sequeslize -cli-typescript successfully?

Comment: Yes, it installed successfully

Comment: + sequelize-cli-typescript@3.2.0-c
updated 1 package in 2.529s

Comment: Do you need sequelize-cli-typescript? I use typescript with sequelize without it

Comment: Hi @Chris, can you provide me a link of any other method of generating migrations?

Comment: Hey @Ashutosh i am facing the same issue while upgrading , did u get any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you also need to install the `sequelize` package locally for the `sequelize init` command to work:

```
npm install sequelize
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation Instructions for sequelize-typescript*

sequelize-typescript requires sequelize

```
npm install sequelize --save // v4

npm install sequelize@3.30.4 --save // or v3

npm install reflect-metadata --save

npm install sequelize-typescript --save
```

Your tsconfig.json needs the following flags:

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

Reference: 
https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript